# Background music destroyed when build index is 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-player

I've got this background sound playing throughout the game.
The problem is that I want it to stop when the scene index is 0.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class BackgroundMusic : MonoBehaviour
{

void Start()
{
    GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("music");
    if (objs.Length > 1)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex != 0)
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

}
```

I've been using this script but still doesn't work
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `DontDestroyOnLoad` it is "forever" you don't have to do it for each scene again.

And then note that after that the `Start` is **not** called for every scene load again only the first time!

Rather use [`SceneManager.sceneLoaded`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) like e.g.

```
public class BackgroundMusic : MonoBehaviour
{

    private static BackgroundMusic _instace;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            return;
        }
        
        DontDestroyOnLoaddd(this.gameObject);
        _instance = this;

        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnDestroy ()
    {
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded -= OnSceneLoaded;
    }

    private void OnSceneLoaded (Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        if(scene.buildIndex == 0)
        {
            // TODO disable música
            // NOTE: I wouldn't Destroy this though but rather only stop the music
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO enable the music
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works just fine even if I get this warning: https://imgur.com/a/G9NKgGX

Comment: @AndreiPreda That warning means the code will never run. Anything after a `return` will not run as the function will terminate at that keyword.

Comment: Oh sorry there was a `}` missing after the return ;)

Comment: :)) Thank you! I was wondering why it was replaying after every scene.

Answer (score 0):

The SIMPLEST way to do this with success :

Check the name of the music and if the name is different, you destroy the Game Object, else you keep it playing and don't destroy it ( exemple : if you die when you are playing, the music continue to play and do not start from the beggining when the level restart, but if you go to the menu or change the level, the music will change without any problem and the old music is destroyed safely. )

Here my own code to solve this problem :

> ```
> private void Awake() {
>     GameObject[] audioSource = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Music");
>     if (audioSource.Length>1)
>     {
>         if (audioSource[0].GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip.name != _audioSource.clip.name)
>         {
>             Destroy(audioSource[0].gameObject);
>         } else {
>          Destroy(this.gameObject);
>         }
>     }
>
>     DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
> }
> ```